# Определить расположение блоков

Tags: css

Есть код:

```
<img src='x.jpg'>
<img src='y.jpg'>
```

О размере их ничего неизвестно. Можно ли определить с помощью CSS — стоят ли блоки рядом или друг под другом.

Comment: javascript тебе в помощь. хотя... если сумеешь написать условие на css...

Comment: т.е. стили для них известны?

Comment: Дефолтные стили. Т.е. "display:inline-block;". Допустим, если они маленькие, то они будут идти рядом, если же большие, то друг под другом. В зависимости от этого, я хотел бы применить к ним определенные стили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял - вы хотите что-то вроде этого?

```
if(($('img.class1').width()+$('img.class2').width())>=$(window).width())
{
    //some styles
}
```

Comment: А что если количество картинок 3, 4, 5...? Было б здорово иметь CSS решение. Пока остается только так

Answer (score 0):

[Координаты элемента](http://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)